# Confusion using Ito product rule in stochastic calculus

Tags: stochastic-calculus

To calculate the Ito differential of the quantity $\frac{A}{B}$ I can use the Ito product rule which gives

$$ 
d (\frac{A}{B})=\frac{dA}{B}-\frac{A}{B^{2}}dB-\frac{1}{B^{2}}dA dB
$$

if I now let $B=A$, I should obtain the result

$$
d(\frac{A}{A})=d(1)=0.
$$

However, substituting into the above the second-order term may be nonzero

\begin{align}
d(\frac{A}{A})&=\frac{dA}{A}-\frac{A}{A^{2}}dA-\frac{1}{A^{2}}dA dA\\
&=-\frac{1}{A^2}dA^2.
\end{align}

Is anyone able to help me understand what I have done wrong here?

Comment: your $d(B^{-1})$ is wrong

Comment: how so, is $d(B^{-1})\neq-\frac{1}{B^2}dB$?

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean it should be $d(B^{-1})=-\frac{1}{B^2}dB+\frac{1}{B^3}dB^2$

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments I incorrectly calculated $d(B^{-1})$ by not taking the chain rule to second order. It should be

$$
d(\frac{A}{B})=\frac{dA}{B}+A(-\frac{1}{B^2}dB+\frac{1}{B^3}dB^2)-\frac{dA dB}{B^2}.
$$

Which is zero upon substituting $A=B$, as it should be. I hope anyone seeing this ends up wasting less time on this than I did.

Comment: It should be $dB^2$ right?

Comment: @Ian thanks for the spot, I've edited it